# Redux firebase - Handle authenticated state properly (first few miliseconds state is null until loaded)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, redux

I'm using firebase with redux in my React app, and encountered few issues here. First one is:

1. After first app start, login with email/pw or login via social (google, fb, apple) does not detect authenticated state (header content depends on authenticated/not authenticated state) until page is refreshed. On every next login, header content changes after login/logout and state change is detected. Workaround is to add `window.location.reload()` after `await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` but I don't want this additional reload.
2. There is initial few milliseconds time when auth state is `null` even user is logged in firebase, on app start or app refresh, until populated and it causes unpropper rendering of some components due to this initial `null` value.

Here is my authentication hook:

```js
export function useAuthentication() {
   const firebase = getFirebase();
   // this token is just additional token from my backend (not related to firebase)
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
         if (!user && !token) {
            setLoggedIn(false);
         } else {
            setLoggedIn(true);
         }
      });
   }, [firebase, token]);

   return { loggedIn };
}
```

How can I improve / add better handling of the authenticated state?

Answer (score 0):

Because authentication is client side, you just need to deal with not knowing the auth state initially (or move your authentication to the server). You can set the initial `isLoggedIn` state to `null` and handle that state in your code until `isLoggedIn` is set to true/false.

```
export function useAuthentication() {
   const firebase = getFirebase();
   // this token is just additional token from my backend (not related to firebase)
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
         if (!user && !token) {
            setLoggedIn(false);
         } else {
            setLoggedIn(true);
         }
      });
   }, [firebase, token]);

   return { loggedIn };
}
```

Now in your code, you can use this:

```
export function MyPageComponent() {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuthentication()

  if (isLoggedIn === null) {
    // Show a loading screen here because you don't have the
    // authentication state so you don't know if the user is
    // logged in or not
    return (<p>Loading</p>)
  }
  // Now `isLoggedIn` will be true/false and you can handle the
  // state properly
  return (
    <MyPageWrapper isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
      ...
    </MyPageWrapper>
  )
}
```